# I'm able to access the object (passed through to this method from props) but I am unable to access the object's data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have passed the props.selectedDish object into this method from the DishDetail functional component and am able to access the object itself. However, when I try to access the data inside the object, only 'undefined' is printed - how can this be? **See DishDetail and RenderDish methods below in addition to the screenshots showing the weird activity going on**:

```
    import {Card, CardBody, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardTitle} from "reactstrap";
import React from "react";
import CardColumns from "reactstrap/es/CardColumns";


function RenderComments(info) {
    console.log('RenderComents', info)
    if (info != null) {
        const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        ];
        let commentsArray = [];
        console.log(info)
        for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            if (info[i] != null) {
                console.log(info)
                commentsArray.push(info.comment);
                commentsArray.push("\n")
                let date = new Date(info.date)
                commentsArray.push("-- " + info.author + ", " + monthNames[date.getMonth() + 1] + ' ' + date.getDay() + ', ' + date.getFullYear())
                commentsArray.push("\n");
            } else {
                console.log('bing')
                return <div></div>
            }

        }
        // info.map((information) => {
        //         if (information != null) {
        //             console.log(information)
        //             commentsArray.push(information.comment);
        //             commentsArray.push("\n")
        //             let date = new Date(information.date)
        //             commentsArray.push("-- " + information.author + ", " + monthNames[date.getMonth() + 1] + ' ' + date.getDay() + ', ' + date.getFullYear())
        //             commentsArray.push("\n");
        //         } else {
        //             console.log('bing')
        //             return <div></div>
        //         }
        //     });
        if (commentsArray != null) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h4> Comments </h4>
                    <p1>{commentsArray.map((line) => {
                        console.log(line)
                        return <p>{line}</p>
                    })}
                    </p1>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return <div></div>
        }


    }

}

const DishDetail = (props) => {
    console.log('DishDetail', props)
    if (props.selectedDish != null) {
        return (
            <div className={'row'}>
                <div className={"col-12 col-md-5 m-1"}>
                    <RenderDish dish={props.selectedDish}/>
                    <RenderComments info={props.selectedDish.comments}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (<div></div>)
    }
}


function RenderDish(dish) {
    console.log('RenderDish', dish)
    // Props is the saved state from the constructor (from the app.js file which
    // gave the DISHES data to the menu component, (which imported it from
    // the DISHES.js file)).
    console.log(dish.comments)
    console.log(dish.name)

    return (

            <Card key={dish.id}>
                <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle> <b>{dish.name}</b> </CardTitle>
                    <CardText> {dish.description} </CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>

    );
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Notice the undefined returns from the console.logs but the full dish object showing in the console.log above!
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> function RenderDish(dish) {

All the props you pass to the component will be passed into `dish` in the above case.

> function RenderDish({ dish }) {

So if you destructure the props like shown above, you'll get actual value you are looking for

Try the following in your `RenderDish` component.

```js
function RenderDish({ dish }) {
    console.log('RenderDish', dish)

    console.log(dish.comments)
    console.log(dish.name)

//rest of the code
}
```

Below is another way of accessing if don't want to use the destructuring

> function RenderDish(props) {

```js
function RenderDish(props) {
    const { dish } = props;
    console.log('RenderDish', dish)

    console.log(dish.comments)
    console.log(dish.name)

//...rest of the code
```

Comment: What did you change? Why? What was incorrect in the original code? Without that information, an answer is not useful.

Comment: @Pointy While mentioning the reason by I have submitted the answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: Ah amazing thanks so much that's fixed it! Out of interest in what instances do you need to use curly brackets in a function in React compared to just the usual function parameters alone?

Comment: If you don't want to access the properties again on the top of the function param you can use `{}` in the function parameter. For example in your case if you want to access `dish` it should be like `dish.dish.name` if we don't use `{dish}`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `info.info`. As the info is essentially `props` that will have an `info` property with the `info` array as can be seen in the console.

Better, destructure out the `info` from `props` in the `RenderComments` Component.

```
function RenderComments({info}) {
  ...
}
```

You'll have to do the same for the `RenderDish`:

```
function RenderDish({dish}) {
    ...
}
```